# generate all combinations of strings based on template

Tags: regex, algorithm, combinations

How to generate all combinations of strings based on template?

For example:
- Template string of

> "{I|We} want {|2|3|4} {apples|pears}"

The curly braces "{...}" identify a group or words, each word separated by "|".

The class should generate strings with every combination of words within each word group.

I know it's finite automata, and also regex. How to efficiently generate combination?

For example

> G[0][j] [want] G[1][j] G[2][j]"

```
G[0] = {I, We}
G[1] = {2, 3, 4}
G[2] = {apples, pears}
```

firstly, generate all possible combination c = [0..1][0..2][0..1]:

```
000
001
010
011
020
021
100
101
110
111
120    
121
```

and then for each c replace G[i][j] by G[i][c[i]]

Comment: It's a job for a programming language not a Regular Expression alone.

Comment: Google it. N/A for regex. Sounds like nested loops though.

Comment: The regular expression above can be saved as a finite tree and a depth-first search gives all the possible strings

Comment: In a loop, C pseudo-code is something like `pI[] = {'I','We'};
pJ[] = {'' ,'2','3','4'};
pK[] = {'apples','pears'};
for ( i = 0; i < 2; i++ )
{
  string strI = pI[i];
  strI += 'want';
  for ( j = 0; j < 4; j++ )
  {
     strJ = strI + pJ[j];
     for ( k = 0; k < 2; k++ )
     {
        strK = strJ + pK[k];
        print( strK );
     }
  }
}`

Comment: @sln template is input (not constant, it's just example)

Comment: It can be generalized to variable input. My code was just an example. It's just common looping, doing the same thing, only the parameters are different. It can be recursive.

Answer (score 3):

Shell glob

```
$ for q in {I,We}\ want\ {2,3,4}\ {apples,pears}; do echo "$q" ; done
I want 2 apples
I want 2 pears
I want 3 apples
I want 3 pears
I want 4 apples
I want 4 pears
We want 2 apples
We want 2 pears
We want 3 apples
We want 3 pears
We want 4 apples
We want 4 pears
```

Answer (score 3):

The most functional solution to this problem I found so far is the Python module [sre_yield](https://github.com/google/sre_yield).

> The goal of sre_yield is to efficiently generate ***all*** values that can
>   match a given regular expression, or count possible matches
>   efficiently.

<sub>Emphasis added by me.</sub>

To apply it to your stated problem: Formulate your template as regex pattern and use it in sre_yield to get all possible combinations or count possible matches like this:

```
import sre_yield
result = set(sre_yield.AllStrings("(I|We) want (|2|3|4) (apples|pears)"))
result.__len__()
result
```

Output:

```
16
{'I want  apples',
 'I want  pears',
 'I want 2 apples',
 'I want 2 pears',
 'I want 3 apples',
 'I want 3 pears',
 'I want 4 apples',
 'I want 4 pears',
 'We want  apples',
 'We want  pears',
 'We want 2 apples',
 'We want 2 pears',
 'We want 3 apples',
 'We want 3 pears',
 'We want 4 apples',
 'We want 4 pears'}
```

PS: Instead of a `list` as shown on the project page I use a `set` to avoid duplicates. If this is not what you want go with a list.

Answer (score 2):

The principle is:

- Regex -> NFA
- NFA -> minimal DFA
- DFS-walk through the DFA (collecting all characters)

This principle is implemented, e.g. in [RexLex](https://github.com/almondtools/rexlex):

```
DeterministicAutomaton dfa = Pattern.compileGenericAutomaton("(I|We) want (2|3|4)? (apples|pears)")
  .toAutomaton(new FromGenericAutomaton.ToMinimalDeterministicAutomaton());
if (dfa.getProperty().isAcyclic()) {
  for (String s : dfa.getSamples(1000)) {
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert each set of strings {...} into a `string array` so you have n arrays.
So for `"{I|We} want {|2|3|4} {apples|pears}"` we would have 4 arrays.

Place each of those arrays into another array. In my example I will call the `collection`

This is Java code, but its simple enough that you should be able to convert it to any language. I didn't test but it should work.

```
void makeStrings(String[][] wordSet, ArrayList<String> collection) {
       makeStrings(wordSet, collection, "", 0, 0);
}

void makeStrings(String[][] wordSet, ArrayList<String> collection, String currString, int x_pos, int y_pos) {

    //If there are no more wordsets in the whole set add the string (this means 1 combination is completed)
    if (x_pos >= wordSet.length) {
        collection.add(currString);
        return; 
    }


        //Else if y_pos is outof bounds (meaning no more words within the smaller set {...} return
    else if (y_pos >= wordSet[x_pos].length) { 
        return;
    } 



    else {
            //Generate 2 new strings, one to send "vertically " and one "horizontally"
            //This string accepts the current word at x.y and then moves to the next word subset
            String combo_x = currString + " " + wordSet[x_pos][y_pos];
            makeStrings(wordSet, collection, combo_x, x_pos + 1, 0);

            //Create a copy of the string and move to the next string within the same subset
            String combo_y = currString;
            makeStrings(wordSet, collection, combo_y, x_pos , y_pos  + 1);
        }
    }
```

*Edit for corrections

Comment: Sorry for the formatting had difficulty with it.

Also if you need the indexes you can just generate another String[] that will add the current indexes [y] as specific words are added